# Is there a method to identify the tables (mysql) each time a user writes or makes a modification?

Tags: mysql

I have bash script to make a mysql database replication system. However I find it a bit very slow so I'm looking for a method that will allow me to know each time a user writes or modifies a table that I can identify the tables in question, save them and restore them. Please give me an idea to idenfy the tables at each modification. Thanks

Comment: What is the reason you are trying to implement your own replication system using `bash` scripts instead of using [MySQL's native replication mechanisms](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)?

Comment: Thanks,
I opted for this solution because by using the native replication threat of mysql, as soon as there is an error (connection, file, special characters), the replication is systematically stopped and no longer continues. However, the script can be executed at a given frequency.

Comment: Replication can be configured to "delay".  That gives you a chance to "roll back the clock".

Comment: Sounds like you need an Audit Trail.  If you save every table every time someone changes a row so can restore a table to that specific point in time, what are you going to do with the other transactions posted during the 15 minutes you verified there is a problem?  With an audit trail, you have the opportunity to document the who, what and when to be a basis for training the troubled person throwing trash your way.  Restoring tables should be a last resort.,Welcome to SO.